# How to create a button inside a Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, button

I am creating a fragment where if I click on the button it should show a Toast message

This is my code:

```
public class Aboutus extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{


    Button ps,fb;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.about_layout, container, false);
         ps = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.ps_btn);
         fb = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.fb_btn);

     try {
         ps.setOnClickListener(this);
     }catch (ActivityNotFoundException exception) {

     }
      //fb.setOnClickListener(this);

      return view;
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.fb_btn:

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "This is my Toast message!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            case R.id.ps_btn:

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "This is my Toast message!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        //you can set the title for your toolbar here for different fragments different titles
        getActivity().setTitle("ABOUT US");
    }
    }
```

My app stops working when I open the fragment.

Comment: `My app is Stoped working when i open the fragment` share your crash log with question

Comment: please share your log

Comment: Show us you `LogCat`. Your `getActivity().setTitle("ABOUT US");` cause a problem, there is no `ToolBar` inside that fragment.

Comment: wats `getActivity.setTitle()` ?

Comment: how about you post the stack trace you get after the crach. Right now we dont even know what error you are getting.

Comment: please edit your question and post crash LOG

Answer (score 0):

It does't seem like having issue with button. There may be a problem with implementing fragment inside activity. Once Watchout Fragment implementation. Thanks.

Comment: If i remove onclicklistener Everything will work fine .But if i add onclicklistener to button it will point error at  here "  ps = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.ps_btn);"

Comment: That means there could be some mistake in inflating button may be in its ID.